# NodeJS application with memory leak, where is it?

Tags: node.js

I have a NodeJs application that listens to messages via subscribe on a Redis server. It collects the messages for a period of 5 Seconds and then pushes them out to the connected clients, the code looks something like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    nClients++;
    console.log("Number of clients connected " + nClients);
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        nClients--;
        console.log("Number of clients remaining " + nClients);
    });
});
```

Receiving messages to send out to the clients

```
cli_sub.on("message",function(channel,message) {
        oo = JSON.parse(message);
        ablv_last_message[oo[0]["base"]+"_"+oo[0]["alt"]] = message;
});

setInterval(function() {
    Object.keys(ablv_last_message).forEach( function(key) {
        io.sockets.emit('ablv', ablv_last_message[key]);
    });
    ablv_last_message = [];
}, 5000);
```

SOLUTION FOUND (at least I think so): Node didn't crash because it reached some internal memory limits, it looks as if it crashed because my VPS ran out of memory, it was a 2GB VPS running one or two other processes too. After upgrading it to 4GB, Node runs smoothly, yes always around 1.6 to 2.0 GB but I believe its the GC who does its work here.

Comment: What symptoms are there of a memory leak?

Comment: The memory increased upto 1.6GB before node crashes. My number of connected clients is rather constant but the memory usage constantly increases

Comment: What happens if you comment out the Socket.io code and replace the call to `io.sockets.emit` by a `console.log` (or even nothing at all)? Is the memory-leak still there? To put it in other words: If it's gone, the memory-leak is somewhere inside your socket handling code, otherwise it's not. This helps to track it down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is better you try some tools for finding leaks in node.js.

**Tools for Finding Leaks**

- Jimb Esser’s [node-mtrace](https://github.com/Jimbly/node-mtrace), which uses the
  GCC mtrace utility to profile heap usage.
- Dave Pacheco’s [node-heap-dump](https://github.com/davepacheco/node-heap-dump) takes a snapshot of the V8 heap and serializes the whole thing out in a huge JSON file. It includes tools to traverse and investigate
  the resulting snapshot in JavaScript.
- Danny Coates’s [v8-profiler](https://github.com/dannycoates/v8-profiler) and [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) provide Node bindings for the V8 profiler and a Node debugging interface using the WebKit Web Inspector.
- Felix Gnass’s fork of the same that [un-disables the retainers graph](http://fgnass.posterous.com/finding-memory-leaks-in-nodejs-applications)
  Felix Geisendörfer’s [Node Memory Leak Tutorial](https://github.com/felixge/node-memory-leak-tutorial) is a short and sweet explanation of how to use the v8-profiler and node-debugger, and is presently the state-of-the-art for most Node.js memory leak debugging.
- Joyent’s SmartOS platform, which furnishes an arsenal of tools at your disposal for [debugging Node.js memory leaks](http://dtrace.org/blogs/bmc/2012/05/05/debugging-node-js-memory-leaks/)

From [Tracking Down Memory Leaks in Node.js – A Node.JS Holiday Season](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/11/tracking-down-memory-leaks-in-node-js-a-node-js-holiday-season/).

And another [blog](http://www.joyent.com/blog/walmart-node-js-memory-leak)

Comment: Thanks for the write up, although it didn't explain the root cause, I think I found it (see my updated post above) but the articles have been more than interesting and very helpful.

Comment: @Damodaran Do you know any solutions that works with 0.10 node version? As far as I tried, any based on v8-profiler fails because of some v8 API differences.

Comment: [HOW TO SELF DETECT A MEMORY LEAK IN NODE](http://www.nearform.com/nodecrunch/self-detect-memory-leak-node/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you keep adding keys to the global `ablv_last_message` object and never clean it.

Comment: It was a copy past mistake into the question here. I reset the global variable with ablv_last_message = [] after having send out the info to the clients. Is that not releasing the allocated memory?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Object.getOwnPropertyNames rather than Object.keys

Comment: That does not solve the constant increase in memory utilization.